# keypress counts too much JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got a problem with a `keypress` event. I have a function that returns `true` or `false` on a `keypress` like this: (simplified a bit)

```
onkeydown (keycode == 88) xKey = true;
onkeyup    (keycode == 88) xKey = false;

if (xKey == true && bombs > 0)

    {
          this.bomb;
          bomb -= 1;
    }
```

Now, when you press the key, it decrements the variable to long, minimal 2 counts which doesn't add to the gameplay of course, I'm not using jQuery which has an unbind attribute and I don't want to add jQuery either, what's the old-school way? I cant find any relevant information on this but I guess I'm not the first to encounter this problem.

Comment: Why don't you just change it to `onkeydown`?

Comment: sorry, I was writing too fast, the onkeypress is already onkeydown.

Answer (score 1):

[onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

onkeypress is both, keydown followed by keyup.

So when you do an onkeypress it will execute the onkeypress code AND the onkeyup code no matter what.

Maybe you want to keep track by using onkeydown instead so it doesn't interfere with the onkeyup functionality.

Comment: I wrote the question wrong, I changed the question already I was using onkeydown already. But the problem remains the same

Comment: anyway, using onkeypress gets me no result at all

Comment: it's pretty hard to figure out what you want to do, I'm assuming you press the button, and hold it so while it's being held, the value is true. Then when you release it it's false? Can you post a jsfiddle of what you have?

Comment: here the whole project so far, this snippet is in index.html and the action is in Player.js

Comment: I want the button to return true just 1 time and then jump to keyup, I believe jQuery does this with unbind but I dont want to add jQuery to the code for just one function.

Comment: FIXED IT !

Wasted my evening, it was so simple and I've done it already before, just overlooked it completly:

if (xKey == true && bomb > 0)

{

xKey = 0;
bombs -= 1;
this.bomb;
}

Sorry for wasting your time, maybe this helps someone else...

GuuuudNight && thanxx 4 your replies.

Answer (score 0):

keypress is fired repeatedly as long as the key is down. you can use keydown or keyup, or augment a throttle through an interval or timeout to only queue the request at the last keypress event

Comment: Thanx, I have a fire button and a bomb wich works but I want to make a    third button that has a charge function or similar but I dont have an idea for it yet. Also everything has to be very low on processing cuz its browser stuff, maybe I'll just start fiddling around until a gameplay element presents  itself ;) as long as were having fun right !?