# .length incrementation and decrementation

Tags: javascript, count

Here's my code in javascript:

```
function length(inputLength){
    this.inputLength = inputLength;
    document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = inputLength.length;
}
```

Normally, when I press a key, a counter is incremented and when I delete a char with the backspace key, the counter is decremented.
The problem is when I delete a char, the count is incremented by 1 too then is decremented normally.
Try this code by using the "onkeydown" event.

Can you help me?

Comment: what is `inputLength` ??? (the parameter passed to the function)

Comment: @ManseUK is the value of the html input.

Comment: I don't really get it? If it's a text input, the length property of the value will always be the correct length (number of characters) of the string?

Comment: Your issue is that your triggering `onkeydown` try using `onkeyup` instead and see what that does.

Comment: @adeneo Normally yes. The length property count how many characters there are is the input.

Comment: Show us how that function is invoked.

Comment: Also, showing us how your getting inputLength would help as that may be where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simplify it and just do this :

```
​function calcLength(elem) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = elem.value.length;
}
```

Where `elem` is the input. Using `elem.value.length` will get the length of the content within the input.

An example of the HTML would be this

```
​<input id="testing" value="" onkeyup="calcLength(this)" />
Length = <span id="output"></span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/dCq4e/)

Comment: It's work, thanks!
The solution is to use "onkeyup" instead "onkeydown".
And thanks for the simplification!

Comment: @MathieuBrochard im not sure the answer was the `onkeyup` vs `onkeydown` it really makes no difference - its just the order of execution ... read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown

Comment: Apparently yes, I've replaced `onkeydown` by `onkeyup` and it's works...
And don't worry, I wanted to validate your answer but I must wait 6 minutes :)