# Cross-Browser Cross-OS way to get keyCode/character pressed onkeydown event

Tags: javascript, dom

For example, if i have this:

```
<input type='text' onkeydown='doSomething()' />

<script>
  function doSomething() {
    // ?
  }
</script>
```

i need to get the keyCode/character pressed in cross-browser/os way.. how to do it? i've tried  about this ~6 years ago and as i remember that time, it was not easy, sometimes i must pass event or something to get it work on opera or IE cmiiw

Comment: isn't the event object handed over to the handler function? what gives: console.log( arguments ); ??

Comment: but what if i need to set onkeydown='doSomething(1,2,3)'?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're close, but the issue with your code is you're executing `doSomething()` in response to `keyDown` events... let's look closely — you're executing `doSomething` *without passing any arguments in*. You're also not naming/accepting arguments, even if you did pass them.

A few quick tweaks to your code and you're all set:

```js
// Notice an `event` argument, containing the important data
function doSomething(event) {
  console.log('****** doSomething');
  console.log('event.keyCode: ', event.keyCode);
  console.log('event.which: ', event.which);
  console.log('event.key: ', event.key);
  console.log('event.code: ', event.code);
}
```

```html
<!-- Notice: We pass the key `event` object into doSomething -->
<input type='text' onkeydown='doSomething(event)' placeholder="Type here..." />
```

## How to determine what key was pressed

I'm confused on this too, but let's review the options. Get ready for some 1995-esque browser differences!

First, keep in mind that while the end goal may be to determine what key was pressed, different methods require different steps to arrive at that. An event can either be a "system and implementation dependent numerical code", a Unicode char value, the Ascii value, or the actual key name ("ArrowUp").

### `event.key` (**TL;DR: Try to use this**)

According to [MDN `KeyboardEvent.key` Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), `event.key` is the recommended way if you're looking for the non-deprecated, "future-forward" way. Documentation is under heavy modification though, so details are sparse on MDN.

Looking at the [caniuse.com support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=event.key) for `event.key`, there's no support below IE11 or on Safari at all (as of Jan 2017). That may already be a deal-breaker, so let's keep looking.

### `event.keyCode`

I've always used `event.keyCode`, which [MDN says is now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and comes with this warning:

> You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use `KeyboardEvent.code`, if it's implemented. Unfortunately, some browsers still don't have it, so you'll have to be careful to make sure you use one which is supported on all target browsers. **Google Chrome** and **Safari** have implemented `KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier`, which was defined in a draft specification but not the final spec.

Alright, fair enough — there's enough differences between browsers and subtle differences between `keydown` and `keypress` events ([not the same thing!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)) to make this not worth using any more. RIP `keyCode`, it's been real!

### `event.which`

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which):

> The numeric code for a particular key pressed, depending on whether an alphanumeric or non-alphanumeric key was pressed. Please see KeyboardEvent.charCode** and **KeyboardEvent.keyCode** for more details.

Another one in the process of deprecation — "This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped."

Ok, well `keyCode` we already know is deprecated too, so what's `charCode` about?

### `event.charCode`

This returns the Unicode char code for a `keypress` event... and [we get another warning from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode):

> Do not use this property anymore, it is deprecated. Use `KeyboardEvent.key` instead.

Starting to chase our own tails here, `KeyboardEvent.key` is the future-forward approach, but not yet adequately supported... it also returns `0` all the time for `keydown` events, you must listen to `keypress` events for this to be valuable.

### `event.code`

The last option seems promising... [`event.code` docs from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code):

> represents a **physical key on the keyboard** (as opposed to the character generated by pressing the key). In other words, this property returns a value which isn't altered by keyboard layout or the state of the modifier keys.

This is handy because we get things like `ShiftRight` versus `ShiftLeft`, useful for game development and very specific interactions. There's a great chart at the bottom of the docs for all code options.

The catch: [not very good support yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=event.code). Nothing on IE, iOS Safari, Android, or Opera.

## So... what should I use?

TBH I don't think there's a one-size-fits all solution. The current landscape seems to require some degree of polyfilling, or at least supporting the old `event.keyCode` and `event.which` properties as fallbacks for where `event.key` and `event.code` can't be used.

For production projects, we just need to consider the browser and device support requirements and go from there.

### Shift/Ctrl/Command/Windows/Etc

There's a few extra properties to check if you care about other keys pressed in combination with the original key:

- [event.altKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey)
- [event.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey)
- [event.metaKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey)
- [event.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey)

### Handy Tool: `keycode.info`

An invaluable tool for quickly figuring out what keyCode you need to write logic around is [http://keycode.info/](http://keycode.info) (created by the v. cool [Wes Bos](http://wesbos.com/))

Answer (score 11):

> ...I've tried about this ~6 years ago...

In modern times...

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener(function(e) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  ...
});
```

**Edit:** Works in "modern" browsers, IE9+ and the rest of the crew.

Comment: *Modern times* are gone I'm afraid. Actually, the results are not consistent any more, [according to my tests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27206737/607407). In the [new W3 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboardevents), they state that there should be `code` and `key` property only (instead of `keyCode`, `charCode`, `keyIdentifier`, `which` and whatnot).