# How can I convert google chrome's .keyIdentifier to something reasonable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, compatibility

So I was doing a script that captures key presses. It's not so easy, because no browser seems to actually follow [the specification of keyboard events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#widl-KeyboardEvent-code).

In firefox, I can observe key codes (which determine specific physical buttons) in `keyCode` property while char codes (which represent letter of the key) in `.charCode`. This is not

When I tried to test in google chrome, I observed different behavior. Google chrome sets all `keyCode`, `charCode` and `which` to the letter value (if exists). However there's a constant value in `keyIdentifier` property. W3 says nothing about such property, but I'd be really happy to make use of it.

How can I convert `keyIdentifier` values (for <kbd>A</kbd> it's `U+0041`) to make them consistent with `keyCode` values appearing in Firefox (for <kbd>A</kbd> it's `65`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with keyboard events for Firefox or Chrome yet, but from the example you posted it seams like Chrome gives you the Unicode representation of the letter 'A' (where the number part is hexadecimal) while Firefox gives you the same number in base 10 (decimal). Making them consistent with each other should therefor be as simple as converting the Firefox number to hexadecimal so you can use the Unicode representation in both browsers.

Answer (score 3):

The actual code is:

```
//Google chrome retardedness
if(event.keyIdentifier) {
  keyCode = parseInt(event.keyIdentifier.substr(2), 16);
}
//not that the other browsers are any closer to something systematic and logical
else {
  keyCode = event.keyCode;
}
```