# Difference between "change" and "input" event for an `input` element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

Can someone tell me what the difference between the `change` and `input` events is?

I am using jQuery for adding them:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

It also works with `input` instead of `change`.

Maybe some difference in the event ordering relative to focus?

Comment: http://rakshasingh.weebly.com/1/post/2012/12/what-is-the-difference-between-oninput-and-onchange-events-in-javascript.html  Note that oninput is not supported in older browser. You could use then: onchange, onpaste and onkeyup as a workaround. PS: oninput event is also buggy in IE9 and it is not fired on deletion.

Comment: input fires more often, like after a keypress, whereas change basically fires when the input is blurred and the value is not what it was when the input was focused.

Comment: The `input` event also captures pasting. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727324/for-a-javascript-autocomplete-search-box-must-we-use-the-input-event-handler

Comment: TLDR: input fires as you type, change fire when you click outside

Answer (score 191, accepted):

According to [this post](http://rakshasingh.weebly.com/1/post/2012/12/what-is-the-difference-between-oninput-and-onchange-events-in-javascript.html):

- **`oninput`** event occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface.
- **`onchange`** occurs when the selection, the checked state, or the contents of an element **have changed**. In some cases, it only occurs when the element loses the focus or when pressing <kbd>return</kbd> (Enter) and the value has been changed. The onchange attribute can be used with: `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`.

TL;DR:

- *`oninput`*: any change made in the text content
- *`onchange`*:

  - If it is an `<input />`: change + lose focus
  - If it is a `<select>`: change option

```js
$("input, select").on("input", function () {
    $("pre").prepend("\nOn input. | " + this.tagName + " | " + this.value);
}).on("change", function () {
    $("pre").prepend("\nOn change | " + this.tagName + " | " + this.value);
}).on("focus", function () {
    $("pre").prepend("\nOn focus | " + this.tagName + " | " + this.value);
}).on("blur", function () {
    $("pre").prepend("\nOn blur | " + this.tagName + " | " + this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<select>
  <option>Alice</option>
  <option>Bob</option>
  <option>Carol</option>
  <option>Dave</option>
  <option>Emma</option>
</select>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: I'm still unclear on the difference between the two. They sound very similar from your descriptions.

Comment: @JustinMorgan Like in the JSFiddle example, the `onchange` occurs "when the element loses the focus" while the `oninput` occurs on every text change.

Comment: The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed.

Comment: In other words "input" is triggered immediately when any character is changed, deleted or added while "change" is evaluated after the control loses focus and happens only when the value has changed

Comment: I just tried with Chrome. `onchange` also gets triggered when you hit enter while still focusing.

Comment: This explanation is very poor, and verges on being *outright wrong*. [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) events fire specifically when the input value is changed *by the user*. [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) fires on *all* value changes, regardless of where they come from.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Select element doesn't lose the focus when its value changes but this answer put `<select>` under `onchange`. Confusing.

Comment: @user3290525 Well, of course you can use the `<select>` with `onchange` and the example is there exactly to see the eventual differences between input and select.

Answer (score 37):

- The `change` `event` fires in most browsers when content is changed and
  the element loses `focus`. It's basically an aggregate of changes. It will not fire for every single change as in the case `input` `event`.
- The `input` `event` fires synchronously on change of the content for the element. As such, the event listener tends to fire more frequently.
- Different browsers do not always agree whether a change event should be fired for certain types of interaction

Comment: I don't think the input event is guaranteed to fire synchronously.

Comment: Also, current versions of all browsers support the `input` event.

Comment: @TimDown, that's why I said browser support varies. Not everyone has the current version of every browser.

Comment: @TimDown Does it fire synchronously?

Comment: @SurajJain: I'm not sure, to be honest.

Comment: @SurajJain What do you mean with *synchronously*? In JavaScript, everything is synchronized with the event loop. This means functions will never be interrupted for running other code in your environment.

Comment: @JojOatXGME I don't get what you are trying to say, i am new in JS.

Comment: @SurajJain I don't know what you mean with *"synchronously"* in this case. With wich operation it might be synchronized?

Answer (score 25):

It seems that this question has become one of the those questions that I visit from time to time. I'm not a fan of reading walls of text for simple things. So I decided to post a practical answer.

Using the following demo, one can examine which events are fired and in what order.

[image: screenshot of the demo]

```js
let eventsToListen = [
    "focus",
    "blur",
    "input",
    "change",
];
let inputs = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll("#inputs :is(input, textarea, select)")
);
inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.eventQueue = [];
    let queueLimit = eventsToListen.length * 2;
    let queueDisplay = input.closest("td").nextElementSibling;
    eventsToListen.forEach(event => {
        input.addEventListener(event, () => {
            input.eventQueue.push(event);
            if (input.eventQueue.length > queueLimit) {
                Array(input.eventQueue.length - queueLimit).fill(null).forEach(
                    _ => input.eventQueue.shift()
                );
            }
            queueDisplay.textContent = input.eventQueue.join(", ");
        });
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
}
#inputs {
    margin: 1em;
}
#inputs td {
    padding: 0.1em;
}
#inputs td:nth-child(2) :not(input[type=radio]):not(input[type=checkbox]) {
    width: 100%;
}
#inputs label {
    display: table;
}
#inputs td:last-child {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
#notices {
    margin: 1em;
}
#notices ul {
    padding-left: 2em;
    line-height: 2;
}
#notices > ul {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
input[type=radio]:focus,
input[type=checkbox]:focus {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<table id="inputs">
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>number</td>
        <td><input type="number" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>textarea</td>
        <td><textarea></textarea></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>select</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>-</option>
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">radio</td>
        <td>
            <label><input type="radio" name="something" /> Option 1</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label><input type="radio" name="something" /> Option 2</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 0.5em">checkbox</td>
        <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="something2" /> Option 1</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<div id="notices">
    notice that:
    <ul>
        <li>"input" event can occur multiple times before a "change" event occurs on text/number/textarea</li>
        <li>"input" and "change" event seem to occur together/sequentially on select</li>
        <li>"input"/"change" event might occur multiple times before a "blur" event occurs on select
            <ul>
                <li>when arrow keys are used to select an option</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. TL;DR: `input` works for all if them if you care about immediate notification. `change` works for all of them if you care about notification on defocus (blur).

Comment: Excellent demo/answer. It shows the 5 most recent events on the right of each input field, with the most recent being on the far right.

Comment: Great answer! I finally get it!

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR: The biggest difference is **what causes the value change**:

- `input` events fire on *any* value changes
- `change` events fire on *direct user-initiated* value changes

  - (The exact details of this vary between input types)

---

The most significant difference between these two events is **what causes** the `value` change on the `<input>`.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event):

> The `input` event fires when the `value` of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed.

In other words, **`input` fires *any time* the `value` changes**.

[`change` is a little bit more complicated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event):

> The `change` event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when an alteration to the element's `value` is committed by the user. Unlike the `input` event, the `change` event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's `value`.

In other words, **`change` fires when *the user* changes the `value`**. In addition, `change` only generally fires when the ending value is *different* than the starting one (as its name suggests).

For `<input>` specifically, the exact timing of the `change` event depends on the input's `type` attribute. In general:

- For text-based input types (e.g: `search`, `text`, `email`, `password`, etc.):

  - When the element loses focus (on blur).
- For inputs that open some sort of interactive menu (e.g. `file`, `date`, `color`, etc.):

  - When the UI element is closed.
  - If the type has a direct text input mechanism (like `date`), then it also fires on *each input* of text (e.g. on each typed digit).
- For non-textual inputs that are interactive (e.g. `checkbox`, `radio`, & `range`):

  - When the element is left in a new state after interacting with it (e.g. click, drag, keyboard shortcut trigger).

There are a few elements with their own nuances, but these are true in the general case.

---

#### Interactive Demo

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputs: [],
    changes: [],
    types: ['text', 'email', 'color', 'file', 'date', 'range'],
  },
  methods: {
    logEvent(e, index) {
      this.$set(this[e.type + 's'], index, e.target.value);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container mw-100 py-3">
    <div v-for="(type, i) in types" class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-2">
        <span>{{ type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1) }}:</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <input :type="type" @input="logEvent($event, i)" @change="logEvent($event, i)" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 text-break">
            <span>Input: <span style="color: red">{{ inputs[i] }}</span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 text-break">
            <span>Change: <span style="color: blue">{{ changes[i] }}</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

MDN documentation has a clear explanation (not sure when it was added):

> The change event is fired for `input`, `select`, and `textarea` elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user. **Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event