# Cannot change input value while setting default value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set default value to an input from another I am entering. However, I can enter data into that box. But I cannot get new value I entered when I submit. Please see my code below:

```
$('.input1').bind('keyup blur', function(){
    $('.input2').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `on("input", function () { ... })`, instead:

```
$('.input1').on('input', function(){
    $('.input2').val($(this).val());
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zW3X2/)

---

Also, see [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17047497/1420197) about the difference between `input` and `change`.