# On change doesn't trigger the function immediately when typing

Tags: jquery

This code is not triggered immediately:

```
$('form').on('change', '#price', function(){
   // code here
});
```

but only when I click from the input box somewhere else.

How to trigger the code even when the user is typing?

Now, it is waiting till he click away from the input box.

Comment: user3018704, do you consider an answer to mark as correct...?

Answer (score 2):

Use `input` instead:

```
$('form').on('input', '#price', function(){
   // code here
});
```

---

### [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input)

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed. Additionally, it's also fired on contenteditable editors when its contents are changed. In this case, the event target is the editing host element. If there are two or more elements which have contenteditable as true, "editing host" is the nearest ancestor element whose parent isn't editable. Similarly, it's also fired on root element of designMode editors.

---

You can use `keyup` and `keydown` events but note that if you use `keyup` or `keydown` when you paste something in your text box/textarea the change will not be fired.

Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17047497/1420197) to see the differences between the two events.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AtvtZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` event to do something when user is typing:

```
$('#price').on('keyup', function() {
     /* do something */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

and a little example reported in that page.

```
 $( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
   alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
 });
```

So when you press a key and the release it, that event is triggered

Answer (score 0):

I presume **#price** is your **input**. ??

To trigger the code when typing you can use this:

```
$('form').on('keyup', '#price', function(){
    // code here
});
```

you could either use **keyup** or **keydown** events

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/