# How to unset PHP element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I'm working on a `php` code and had this headache I had been battled for weeks. I have a search option list using `<select>`, and if I choose one option, it automatically open another search option list, and the proceed keeps on going. A simple version of it could be found here:

```
<?php 
echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action=".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].">";
echo "<select name='select1' onchange='submit()'>";
echo "<option value=''> default </option>";
echo "<option value='a'> a </option>";
echo "<option value='b'> b </option>";
echo "</select>";

if(isset($_POST["select1"])) {
    echo "<select name='select2' onchange='submit()'>";
    echo "<option value='c'> c </option>";
    echo "<option value='d'> d </option>";
    echo "</select>";
    if(isset($_POST["select2"])) {
        echo "<select name='select3'>";
        echo "<option value='e'> e </option>";
        echo "</select>";
    }
}
echo "</form>";

The search result number is: X
?>
```

All option data and search result number are pulled from `SQL` Database and changed depend on `$_POST["select1"]` and `$_POST["select2"]`.

My problem is, for example, if I choose **a (select1)** -> **c (select2)** -> **e (select3)**, then change my mind and choose **b (select1)**, `$_POST["select2"]` is still set, thus making **select3** visible and search result is wrong.

The best answer I can come up with it to unset `$_POST["select2"]` if the value of **select1** changes, that means with `onChange` function from `JavaScript`.

My failed attempt:

- Create `onChange` function with `submit()` and another function for `php` ([Call 2 functions within onChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435611/call-2-functions-within-onchange-event)), in the second function used:
  `document.getElementById("demo") = ' <?php //php code ?>  ';`
- Using `JQuery`: [How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript) (I don't know if I had applied method the wrong way, as I have zero experiences in JavaScript)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use `unset` for this? This is not possible, as PHP and Javascript run independently. You should use AJAX for this

Comment: How can I achieve my goal with AJAX then? Can you give me some hint to begin with? I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript/23741119 but I still don't have any idea how to apply my sql-related php code into AJAX.

Comment: Well, you have to write some code for that :) There is no such thing as a global tutorial for this question, but you could start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991067/populating-a-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-and-php