# Angular 2 - how to handle change detection in a directive

Tags: angular

I've got an input field that I have attached a directive to.

```
<input type="email" 
       id="email" 
       formControlName="email" 
       email
       [placeholder]>
```

The directive is placeholder, when a user updates the input with a new value I want to run some code in the directive:

```
  @Input() public input: String;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('change') ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('test');
  }
```

I thought I'd need to use the hostListener directive to check for a change but this isn't working as I intended. My intention is to add a class when the input has a value inside of it.

What do others do to achieve this?

Comment: *isn't working as I intended* - and how did you intend? The question lacks clear problem statement. Since you set up a listener on `change` event, you can be sure that it will be triggered on this event.

Comment: Thanks good point. I've just added to my question of my intent.

Comment: Related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047497/what-is-the-difference-between-change-and-input-event-for-an-input-element

Comment: how does this relate?

Comment: The event you're likely looking for is `input`, not `change`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Template Driven Form and Define input property binding as below in your template

```
 <input type="email" 
    id="email" 
    [(ngModel)]="email"
    [input]="email"  
    placeholder>
```

Directive.ts

```
     @Input() public input: String;
     constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
     @HostListener('change') ngOnChanges() {
      console.log('test');
       }
```

it might help and also check this example 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-na4ncb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use de OnChange

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[my-directive]'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnChanges {
   @Input('value-listen') public formControl: any;

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
     console.log(changes);
   }
```

}

Only should pass the formControl in [value-listen]="yourValue"