# Recalculate a number on change event using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, calculation

I'm building a simple multiplication form which calculates a sum and renders the answer direct to the DOM. I'm using a `<select>` menu to choose the initial number and an `<input type="number">` for the multiplier.

Is it possible to recalculate the answer and render it to the DOM automatically when changing the `<select>` value? The form currently works but the user will need to delete the multiplier after re-selecting the initial number.

Here's where I currently am:

```js
const selectValIn = document.querySelector(".select-val-in");
const inputValIn = document.querySelector(".input-val-in");
const valOut = document.querySelector(".val-out");
let multiplier = 2;

selectValIn.addEventListener("change", switchValIn);
inputValIn.addEventListener("keyup", convert);

function switchValIn() {
  let selectedVal = selectValIn.value;

  if (selectedVal === "four") {
  multiplier = 4;
  } else if (selectedVal === "six") {
  multiplier = 6;
  } else if (selectedVal === "eight") {
  multiplier = 8;
  }
}

function convert(e) {
  const inputValIn = e.target.value;
  const multiplication = inputValIn * multiplier;

  valOut.innerText = multiplication;
}
```

```html
<div class="converter">
  <div class="converter-row">
    <select class="select-val-in">
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option value="six">6</option>
    <option value="eight">8</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="converter-row">
  <label>Multiplied by:</label>
  <input class="input-val-in" type="number" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="converter-row">
  <p>Equals: <span class="val-out">0</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a Codepen with a working example: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/59776227c017d1c1a3a245a37c305e76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following example. Also take a look at the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047497/what-is-the-difference-between-change-and-input-event-for-an-input-element) to see the difference between `change` and `input`.

```js
const selectValIn = document.querySelector(".select-val-in");
const inputValIn = document.querySelector(".input-val-in");
const valOut = document.querySelector(".val-out");

selectValIn.addEventListener("input", calculate);
inputValIn.addEventListener("input", calculate);

function calculate()
{
  valOut.innerText = Number(inputValIn.value) * Number(selectValIn.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="converter">
  <div class="converter-row">
    <select class="select-val-in">
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="converter-row">
    <label>Multiplied by:</label>
    <input class="input-val-in" type="number" value="0" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="converter-row">
    <p>Equals: <span class="val-out">0</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that a switch might have been easier to read:

```
// Easier to read
switch(selectedVal)
{
 case 'two':
  multiplier = 2;
  break;
case 'four':
  multiplier = 4;
  break;
case 'six':
  multiplier = 6;
  break;
case 'eigth':
  multiplier = 8;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I was looking for. I guess using a switch would work if the option value wasn't a number?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than storing the changes, just call the calculation function when something changes and get the values there. Removing state makes the functions simpler and less error-prone.

```js
// Selectors

const selectValIn = document.querySelector(".select-val-in");
const inputValIn = document.querySelector(".input-val-in");
const valOut = document.querySelector(".val-out");

// Calculate

function calculate() {
 const value = Number(inputValIn.value);
 const multiplier = Number(selectValIn.value);
 valOut.innerText = value * multiplier;
}

// Event listeners

selectValIn.addEventListener("change", calculate);
inputValIn.addEventListener("input", calculate);
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.converter-row {
 margin: 0 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="converter">
 <div class="converter-row">
  <select class="select-val-in">
   <option value="2" selected>2</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="converter-row">
  <label>Multiplied by:</label>
  <input class="input-val-in" type="number" value="0" />
 </div>
 <div class="converter-row">
  <p>Equals: <span class="val-out">0</span></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing your inputValIn as well as your multiplier? This way, you can just do a check inside of your switchValIn function to see if the inputValIn already exists, in which case you can just do the multiplication and render immediately.

Another approach is to set a default inputValue so you never have to do the check and instead run the multiplication every time either of them changes

Comment: Your answer would be more usefull for the OP and future visitors if you would show what you mean. You can do this by providing some code in the answer