# IE11+vue.js: <input type="checkbox" v-on:input="blabla()"> doesn't work/fire

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js

A vue.js template containing this doesn't fire in IE11:

```html
<input type="checkbox" v-on:input="blabla()">
```

`blabla()` *is* called in Firefox and Chrome - just not in IE11.

Why is that? See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/pmorch/pen/joRxjv) to reproduce. In IE11, you'll need the [codepen debug view](https://s.codepen.io/pmorch/debug/joRxjv/NjkYzqgqvXNM) though, as the codepen editor is not supported in IE11.

Using vue 2.6.10, which today is the newest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't fire an `input` event, but a `change` event for checkboxes. Firefox and chrome fire both. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047497/difference-between-change-and-input-event-for-an-input-element) for more.

I've updated the codepen to show both `v-on:input` and `v-on:change`.

It does mean that the [vue.js doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) is a little incomplete. It says:

> Remember that:

```
<input v-model="searchText">
```

> does the same thing as:

```
<input
  v-bind:value="searchText"
  v-on:input="searchText = $event.target.value"
>
```

But clearly that is not true for `<input type="checkbox">`.

(So I found the answer myself, I just wanted to record it here for the next poor guy who comes up against it.)