# can excute fonction when value of input was changed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i create this directive for find when the value of input was changed to somthing .

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ktCloseDatePciker]'
})
export class CloseDatePcikerDirective {


  constructor() { }
  @HostListener('change', ['$event'])
  click(event) {
    console.log('clicked!');
  }

}
```

and use that in the html by this :

```
                <input #dateDirectivePicker="dpDayPicker" ktCloseDatePciker (change)="close()" formControlName="Publish_CalendarDate" id="date-lrt" theme="dp-material" matInput mode="daytime" [dpDayPicker]="datePickerConfigStart" />
```

but it not worked , when i change the value it can not write console in driective.

**whats the problem ? how  can solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 0):

Change the event's name from `'change'` to `'input'`, [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ymia4):

**`directive`**

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[ktCloseDatePciker]"
})
export class CloseDatePcikerDirective {
  constructor() {}
  @HostListener("input", ["$event"])
  input(event) {
    console.log("typed!" + event.target.value);
  }
}
```

**`template`**

```html
<input ktCloseDatePciker (change)="close()"/>
```

The `'change'` event is triggered when the input loses focus, which is how it was intended to be used ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17047607/4051471)):

[MDN input event:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

> **Note**: The input event is fired every time the value of the element
> changes. This is unlike the change event, which only fires when the
> value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a
> value from a list of options, and the like.

Comment: i can not type any thing on that . i have datepicker on that input , when i select the date it set value on the input but not write any things in console

Comment: @kianoushdortaj please check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyc6gs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclose-date-pciker.directive.ts), i tried reproducing your issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onChange event instead of change to get picker changes.
and need to use close event for when the picker closed.

> for changes :

```
 <input #dateDirectivePicker="dpDayPicker" ktCloseDatePciker (onChange)="close()" formControlName="Publish_CalendarDate" id="date-lrt" theme="dp-material" matInput mode="daytime" [dpDayPicker]="datePickerConfigStart" />
```

> when closed picker :

```
<input #dateDirectivePicker="dpDayPicker" ktCloseDatePciker (close)="close()" formControlName="Publish_CalendarDate" id="date-lrt" theme="dp-material" matInput mode="daytime" [dpDayPicker]="datePickerConfigStart" />
```