# not subscribe after debouceTime in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want when use input data after 300 millisecond `emit` data for doing this i using the debouceTime :

```
subject: Subject<any> = new Subject();

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit();

sendValue(): void {
 this.subject.pipe(debounceTime(300))
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.formValue.emit(this.dynamicForm.value);
  })
}
```

and this is html :

```
  <input
     (change)="sendValue()"
     required
     [formControlName]="controls.controlName"
     matInput
  />
```

but it not execute subscribe after 300 millisecond .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `(input)` instead of `(change)`. Why? [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17047607/8593983)
- You should call `.next()` on `Subject`, then only streaming continues and `.subscribe()` will get new data

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" (input)="sendValue()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="lastname" (input)="sendValue()">
</form>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  fg: FormGroup;
  inputSubject = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
    });

    this.inputSubject
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
      )
      .subscribe(
        () => console.log(this.fg.value)
      );
  }

  public sendValue() {
    this.inputSubject.next();
  }
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zphcvh)

Comment: thank for help me . i have one querstion about this . when i shuld the un subscribe ???

Comment: When the component is destroyed you can unsubscribe. Angular has lifecycle hook `ngOnDestroy()`. In that method you can call `this.inputSubject.unsubscribe()`

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a RxJS `Subject` observable and subscribing to it directly. Unless any value is pushed to it, it won't emit. Using an external observable is unwarranted in this situation.

What you could do is to use the [`valueChanges`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) observable of the [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#formcontrol). You don't need the binding to `change` event as well. The `valueChanges` will emit anytime the value of the element changes since it's a `FormControl` element.

Try the following

Control

```js
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.controls.controlName.valueChanges.pipe(          // <-- form control here
    debounceTime(300)
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.formValue.emit(this.dynamicForm.value);
  });
}
```

Template

```html
<input
   required
   [formControlName]="controls.controlName"
   matInput
/>
```

#### Update: combine multiple observable

If you have multiple controls, one way would be to combine all the `valueChanges` observables using RxJS [`merge`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) function.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  merge(
    this.controls.controlName.valueChanges,  
    this.controls.controlPhone.valueChanges,  
    this.controls.controlId.valueChanges,
    ...  
  ).pipe(
    debounceTime(300)
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.formValue.emit(this.dynamicForm.value);
  });
}
```

Comment: i put the on of  `formControl` in my html . They are very many . i cant set valueChange for all of them