# Difference between @input or @change with Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify on a project and wanted to know what is the difference in the documentation on a `v-text-field` component between the `input` and the `change` events ?

Here is the description of those events, if any of you faced the subject and found any answers I'll be glad to know :

@Change - V-Text-Field
[image]

@Input - V-Text-Field
[image]

Comment: `@change` is triggered when you unfocus the field or releasing a mouse action when `@input` is triggered when hitting a key. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/posva/oqe9e8pb/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "change" and "input" event for an \`input\` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047497/difference-between-change-and-input-event-for-an-input-element)

Comment: update is also used for the `v-model` by default