# How to display input value on page in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to display input value on the website? I already tried to display it but when I change the value of the input, the display is still the same.

```js
const rangeInput = document.querySelector(".range");
const valueInp = document.querySelector(".value");

valueInp.innerHTML = rangeInput.value;
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1" class="range"/>
<p class="value"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did puts the value of the input in the paragraphe on load. Plus you need an EventListener in order to track the input changes, like so:

```js
const rangeInput = document.querySelector(".range");
const valueInp = document.querySelector(".value");
valueInp.innerHTML = rangeInput.value;
rangeInput.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
 valueInp.innerHTML = rangeInput.value;
})
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1" class="range"/>
<p class="value"></p>
```

Comment: Hello, this code actually works but is there anyway, to make value change while we move a circle

Comment: That is what the code is doing, or I didn't understand your question.

Comment: replace change with mouseover @Excortia you will get what you want

Comment: @NileshMishra Actually you want the `'input'` event, not the `'change'` event. Using `mouseover` or `mousemove` is inappropriate because the user might not be using a mouse.

Comment: @NileshMishra it's not working

Comment: @Dai thanks i got a result

Comment: Try with the input  event @Dai suggestted I just edited my answer. Tell me if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const rangeInput = document.querySelector(".range");
const valueInp = document.querySelector(".value");
rangeInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
  valueInp.textContent = rangeInput.value;
});
valueInp.textContent = rangeInput.value;
```

````html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1" class="range"/>
<p class="value"></p>```
````

Comment: In case anyone needs

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the `<p>` element for the value will always be following directly after your range element then the following script will take care of any number of range/value combinations:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".range")
.forEach(r=>r.addEventListener("input",update(r)));

function update(r){
  const ur= ()=>r.nextElementSibling.textContent=r.value;
  ur();
  return ur;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="40" step="1" class="range"/>
<p></p>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="20" step="1" class="range"/>
<p></p>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="30" step="1" class="range"/>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1" class="range"/>
<p class="value"></p>
```

```
const rangeInput = document.querySelector(".range");
const valueInp = document.querySelector(".value");
range.addEventListener("change",()=>{
   valueInp.innerHTML = rangeInput.value;
})
valueInp.innerHTML = rangeInput.value;
```

addEventListener here will be executed whenever value inside input tag is **changed** .

Comment: Yep, this code works too but is there anyway, to make value change while we move a circle

Answer (score -1):

- You need to wire-up an event-listener on the `<input/>` which then updates the `<p class="value">` in the event-handler.
- You can only wire-up event-handlers *after* `DOMContentLoaded` btw.
- [There are two main events you can listen to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047497/difference-between-change-and-input-event-for-an-input-element):

  - Use the `'input'` event to respond to every change-in-value, even while the `<input>` element has focus.
  - Use the `'change'` event to only respond to changes when the user has stopped interacting with the input.
- BTW, [you should use an `<output>` element instead of `<p>` for showing "output" values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output).
- You should use `id` to select specific elements instead of `.className` selectors because `class=""` is not unique.
- **Never use `innerHTML` for showing text** as it opens you up to XSS attacks.

  - For `<output>` you can set `HTMLOutputElement.value`.
  - For all other elements, use `textContent`.
  - [Or `innerText`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext).

Like so:

```js
window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', onDomLoaded );

function onDomLoaded() {

    const rangeInput = document.getElementById('myRangeInput');
    const output     = document.getElementById('myOutput');

    // Show initial value immediately:
    output.textContent = rangeInput.value;

    // 'input' is the name of the event-type, not the <input> element name.
    // you can also use 'change' instead.
    rangeInput.addEventListener( 'input', e => {
        output.textContent = rangeInput.value;
    } );
}
```

```html
<input id="myRangeInput" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1" class="range"/>
<output id="myOutput" for="myRangeInput"></output>
```

---

If you want something really succinct, then just update the `<output>` dire [use a named `<output>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-output-element) the `oninput=""` attribute, like so:

```html
<input id="myRangeInput" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1" oninput="document.getElementById('myOutput').value = this.value;" />
<output id="myOutput" for="myRangeInput"></output>
```

Comment: Hello, i have a question with your code, why we add event on window?

Comment: @Excortia Because you cannot (reliably) use `getElementById` before the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired.