# HTML slider changing event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bulma

```
<input class="slider is-fullwidth is-large is-primary" step="1" min="0" max="100"  type="range" id="some_id" value="15">

<script>
    $(".slider").change(function() {
   ...
}
</script>
```

This event works, but only when I have released the mouse/finger from the (bulma) slider. Is there a way to  make jQuery to notify me while the slider is changing without the need to release the mouse/finger?

Comment: Have you tried `input` instead of `change`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17047497/1427878

Comment: `change` events only fire at the end of the change, not during.  **edit** As noted above [input event](https://jsfiddle.net/cpuqbtj6/) works fine.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "bulma slider"?  Seems like it's a normal `<input type=range>` as [tag:bulma] is a css framework, it won't have a bulma-slider.