# how to check a field without the mouse moving and without validation

Tags: javascript

Hello I would like to know if it is possible to trigger an event on a form field

For example I have a name field in a form

I would like the error message to disappear when the person starts to fill in the field

But if the person removes the characters the error message comes back

Without any form validation

As you can see on my code for now I check the field on mouseover

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ville = document.querySelector('[name="ville"]');
  if (ville !== null && ville.value !== '')
  { 
    document.getElementById("myImgaa").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/img_pulpit.jpg";
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("myImgaa").src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML DOM Events</h1>
<h2>The onmousemove Event</h2>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="ville" value="" id="ville" placeholder="" required="required" />
<div style ="width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;"onmousemove="myFunction(event)" ></div>
<img id="myImgaa" src="" width="107" height="98">
```

Comment: which error message? can you please provide more details

Comment: I have no error message
I would like input to be red if empty and yellow if a character in it

Comment: you mean input element or the text inside it ?

Comment: and what about the image? give me more details so i can solve your problem

Comment: sorry I expressed myself badly I would like the image to be displayed if a letter in the input field and the field turns yellow

if no letter in the input then no image and input in red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **input** event which occur whenever you **type in** or **delete** charachter, for example if you type ABC this event will **trigger 3 times**

alternatively you can use **change** event which occur when the value changed, for ABC this will trigger **once you leave the input**

to know the difference between both events you can check out this link [Difference between "change" and "input" event for an `input` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047497/difference-between-change-and-input-event-for-an-input-element)

by default i hide the image with `display: none;` css property and once you type in i remove this class so the image will appear

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector("#ville"),
      img = document.querySelector("#myImgaa");

inputEl.addEventListener("input", () => {
  if (inputEl.value == "") {
    inputEl.classList.add("red");
    inputEl.classList.remove("yellow");
    img.classList.add("d-none");
  } else {
    inputEl.classList.add("yellow");
    inputEl.classList.remove("red");
    img.classList.remove("d-none");
  }
});
```

```css
.red, input {
    border: 2px solid red;
    outline: red;
}

.yellow {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    outline: yellow;
}

/* Hide an element */
.d-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="ville" value="" id="ville" placeholder="" required="required" />
<div style ="width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;" ></div>
<img id="myImgaa" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/img_pulpit.jpg" width="107" height="98" class="d-none">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code and the explanation
But if I have several inputs I have to duplicate the code

Comment: you don't need to duplicate you can use arrays instead and loop through it, and give your input elements a css class so you can select them all with document.querySelectorAll and do the same for each one

Answer (score 1):

You can try and bind to the keypress event for the element:

```
const ville = document.querySelector('[name="ville"]');
ville.addEventListener("keyup" , myFunction);
```

The above would need to be outside of your function. An event object will be sent to your function, e.g.: `myFunction(e){}`
You an also use keyup or keydown events.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#texte").keyup(function(){
    const nom = document.querySelector('[name="nom"]');
    
    if (nom !== null && nom.value !== '')
    { 
      document.getElementById("textezz").innerHTML="le champ n'est plus vide";
      $(this).css("background-color", "lightBlue");
    } else { 
      document.getElementById("textezz").innerHTML="vous devez remplir votre nom";
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  });
});
</script>

<label for="texte">Ecrivez dans le champ : </label>
<input type="text" id="texte" name="nom">

<div id="textezz"></div>
```