# How to trigger search input event using a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire input's `on.input` event if value is changed not by typing
Type something inside the input and then click the button

```js
$('.inpsearch').on('input', function(){
    let a = $(this).val();
  console.log(a);
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.inpsearch').val('');
  // console.log expected here
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' class='inpsearch'>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either `trigger` the `input` event as in my snippet or separate that functionality into a function and call it.

```js
$('.inpsearch').on('input', function(){
    let a = $(this).val();
  console.log(a);
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.inpsearch').val('');
    $('.inpsearch').trigger('input');
  // console.log expected here
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' class='inpsearch'>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: it works thanks. My logic was something like `$('.inpsearch').input()`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the input event is relatively new and only available to modern browsers (IE9+), verify [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent)

Here is the really good described [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727891/8987128) about events.

My suggestion is to use `keyup` event instead of `input` event, Much like keydown, it triggers whenever the user releases a key, i have also implemented in your example:

```js
$('.inpsearch').on('keyup', function(){
    let a = $(this).val();
    console.log(a);
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.inpsearch').val('');
    $('.inpsearch').trigger('keyup');
    // console.log expected here
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' class='inpsearch'>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

> Note that `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup` events carry with them information about the modifier keys `Ctrl`, `Shift` and `Alt` in the properties `ctrlKey`, `shiftKey` and `altKey` respectively and `input` event will not.