# Capture Global Keystrokes in Browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to use Javascript within a browser environment to detect global keystrokes and mouse movements (i.e. all keystrokes and clicks within and outside the browser)? I understand this might involve browser plugins, but would like advice on specific pieces of technology I can look into.

Comment: If you want to deal with "outside the browser", then you need something listening at the OS level.

Comment: In addition to above comment, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, this is not possible** and that's a damn good thing. We don't need random websites to act as keyloggers.

Any browser plugin allowing a website to do that would actually be malware or at least open a gaping security hole and thus end up on the plugin blacklists of browser vendors really soon.