# Call specific method in javascript when enter key pressed anywhere in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to call a method when "enter" key is pressed anywhere in page but i don't want register any method call in each text box. I know it can be done by jQuery like this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    // enter pressed
  }
});
```

Kindly tell me how can I write same version of this code in plain javascript?
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Comment: Why don't you want jQuery?  It is the same thing with a simpler API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('cilcked')
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/448vuooe/3/)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", yourKeyDownFunction, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZDxw/1/