# Adding / removing class from only visible <img> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

EDIT: the difference between the suggested duplicate thread and my thread is I'm wondering how to target only the visible img and toggle a class on and off for it.

I have an interesting situation I hope to get some help with. Before I go any further this is the site: [www.travelandlifestylephotography.com](http://www.travelandlifestylephotography.com)

I'm using [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) on that site. However I am wanting to do something that is outside the scope of that plugin so I need some help as I am just learning HTML/CSS and know almost nothing about Javascript.

**This is what I want to do:** I want the background image on just the active slide to go from "background-size: cover" to "background-size: contain" **when the user presses the "space" key**. If they press the space key again I want the image to go back to "background-size: cover". When I say "active" slide I mean that fullpage.js adds an "active" class to the "slide" class currently being viewed. I want this change to only affect the background image of the slide being viewed and not any other slide.

**How things are coded:**

```
<div class="slide loading">
    <img class="lifestyle1 background_cover" /> 
</div>
```

And the CSS this way:

```
.lifestyle1 {
    background-image: url("/img/lifestyle/1Lifestyle.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 30%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-size: contain;
    z-index: -1;
}

.background_cover {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

So you can see, if I can somehow remove the "background_cover" class from just the active image the background image will revert back to having "background-size: contain".

So, that's my question. I hope it was clear and concise. :) Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Use `$('img:visible').addClass('someClass');`

Comment: Why not use a simple CSS rule? `.active img`

Comment: I left out a very important bit of information. I want this to happen when the user presses the space bar. Can't believe I left that out. Kind of important. :)

Comment: Its really sounds like a XY problem imo

Comment: If there's a better way of removing a class when a certain key is pressed and placing it back when the same key is pressed again, I'm open to changing the way I have this setup. It just needs to change only the visible image.

Comment: **1.** Bind key(up|down|press) event **2.** Get the keyCode from the `event` object and check if it is the interested key **3.** Use `toggleClass` to toggle class from an element.  Follow these steps, when stuck ask question with complete code and attempts.

Comment: [Google tells me the keycode for space is "32".](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)  I'll see what I can get worked out with toggleclass events.

Comment: So I'm going to post something I've hacked together but I'm sure I've got this horribly wrong because I know almost nothing about javascript (yet).
  
    `$(function () {  
    $("slide").bind("keydown", function (e) {  
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {  
    $("img:visible").toggleClass('background_cover');  
    };  
    });  
    };`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below function:

```
$(function () { 
  $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        $(".slide.active > img").toggleClass('background_cover'); 
    }
  });
});
```

Bind to keyup ensures that the function will not get repeatedly called if the key is kept depressed.

.slide.active get you the currently selected slide.

Comment: That did it! Ok so now I see you are using ">" to select only the img in the slide with active class. Thanks for your help. PS - I ended up using the shift key. I forgot space key scrolls down.

Comment: @dsiglin `>` selects the img only if it is the immediate child in .slide (as it is your case). `$(".slide.active img")` also works, but `>` makes it more specific.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I have a lot to learn.

For anyone reading this - I discovered that "background_cover" has to come after the "lifestyle1" class in the CSS file. It also has to be in the same CSS file. I have two different CSS files and having "background_cover" in the other CSS file didn't work.

Comment: @dsiglin It need not be in the same CSS file. Might be because the other CSS file was included before the one with "lifestyle1" class. The way css works is, the last one takes overwrites the property having same specificity. So `background-size: contain;` in lifestyle1 would overwrite `background-size: cover;` if lifestyle1 is defined afterwards.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but "main.css" comes after "backgrounds.css". I probably messed something else up somewhere.