# Keyboard shortcut for MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How can we use Keyboard shortcut for MVC application?. My requirement is when I press **Ctrl+U** , I want to load my home page and when I press **Ctrl+T**, nedd to open another page. How it is possible in client side.
Please help.

Regards
Sreyas MN

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, ASP.NET MVC has no built-in keyboard short cuts, you will need to use jQuery or JavaScript to capture these events and wire them to some event handler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

**Capture the Events via Javascript.**

*KeyCode for Ctrl+U and Ctrl+ T using below code*

```
$(document).bind('Keydown',function(event){
if(event.KeyCode== Keycode) // check for Keycode for Ctrl+U and Ctrl+ T
{
window.location.href(url);
}
});
```

**use target="_blank" to open in new tab.**

Answer (score 0):

Just capture keyboard events on client script, when your desired key combinations fire redirect your code execution to the desired controllers with location.href

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [jquery hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

jQuery Hotkeys supporting almost any key combination.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+T', function(){ 

// Do what ever youwant 

});
```