# Javascript counter on key input instead of button?

Tags: javascript, counter

So I have this counter that increments 'positive' and 'negative' values, it's working fine. Now I also want to assign keyboard key to increment the values, 'f' for negative and 'j' for positive. How do I do this?
I have been fiddling with onkeypress/onkeyup but it is still confusing.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function modify_qty(val) {
var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

if (new_qty < 0) {
    new_qty = 0;
}

document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
return new_qty;
}

function modify_qtyn(val) {
var qtyn = document.getElementById('qtyn').value;
var new_qtyn = parseInt(qtyn,10) + val;

if (new_qtyn < 0) {
    new_qtyn = 0;
}

document.getElementById('qtyn').value = new_qtyn;
return new_qtyn;
}

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">    
    <label for="Positive"><abbr title="Positive">Qty</abbr></label>
    <label for="Negative"><abbr title="Negative">Qtyn</abbr></label>
    <input id="qtyn" value="0" />
    <input id="qty" value="0" />
    <button id="down" onclick="modify_qtyn(1)">MINUS</button>
    <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">PLUS</button>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I found the solution by adding this:

```
function code(e) {
e = e || window.event;
return(e.keyCode || e.which);
}
window.onload = function(){
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    var key = code(e);
    if (key==102) {modify_qtyn(1);}
    if (key==70) {modify_qtyn(1);}
    if (key==106) {modify_qty(1);}
    if (key==74) {modify_qty(1);}
   };
};
```

Comment: you want to trigger function `modify_qtyn` when keyboard key is pressed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych yes, basically assign that to a button.

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid  there are few right answers below

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event `keypress` in the tag `<body>` or even in the `window`. Check the documentation of this [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress).

```
<body onkeypress="func(event)">
```

or

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', func);
```

sor in this `func` you read the `event.key` passed as the first parameter to verify if is letter "f" or "j".

Answer (score 0):

**method 1: addEventListener to body-**

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  console.log(e.which) 
  if(e.which==70){ // 102
     modify_qtyn(1);
   }else if(e.which == 74){ // 106
     modify_qtyn(-1);
   }
});
```

**method 2: input type to number to use arrow key**

```
<input id="qtyn" value="0" type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding this:

```
function code(e) {
e = e || window.event;
return(e.keyCode || e.which);
}
window.onload = function(){
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    var key = code(e);
    if (key==102) {modify_qtyn(1);}
    if (key==70) {modify_qtyn(1);}
    if (key==106) {modify_qty(1);}
    if (key==74) {modify_qty(1);}
   };
};
```