# Remove keydown event listener

Tags: javascript

Trying to remove the `keydown` event listener. It says I need to use a named function. Isn't `doStuff()` a named function? Why doesn't it work? I wan't to remove the `keydown` event if someone types they `E` key. So after `E` the console should not long anymore anything. What am I doing wrong?

```js
(function(){
  'use strict'

  class Blubb {
      constructor() {
          this.init();
      }
      
      init() {
          document.addEventListener('keydown', (function(event) {
              this.doStuff(event);
          }).bind(this));
      }
      
      doStuff(event) {
          if(event.keyCode === 69) {
              console.log('remove event listener', event.keyCode);
              document.removeEventListener('keydown', (function(event) {
                  this.doStuff(event);
              }).bind(this));
          } else {
              console.log('blubb', event.keyCode);
          }
      }
  };
  
  new Blubb();

})();
```

```html
<h3>Press key on keyboard</h3>
<h3>Press "E" to remove Event Listener</h3>
```

Comment: Try without bind

Comment: Add `this.doStuff = this.doStuff.bind(this)` in constructor and then use `document.addEventListener('keydown', this.doStuff);` and `document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.doStuff)`.

Comment: a named function is when you use something like this addEventListener('event', namedFunction) and removeEventListener('event', namedFunction)

Comment: @dfsq thank you! that solved it!

Comment: @dfsq, nice try. I really wish this would work, but ... alas! it doesn't. I still get key responses after I press 'E'. This stuff is a big pain!

Comment: Whoever closed this thread saying that "There is already an answer", he/she has to know what he/she is doing. Because 1) the link contains **NO `keydown` events** (which is asked for here) and 2) all the answers include **mouse clicking** !! (In short, the link does not offer an answer to **this** question.)

Comment: @Apostolos is doesn't matter if it is `keydown` or `click` event as they are all `events`. [See dfsq comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353322/remove-keydown-event-listener?noredirect=1#comment81658907_47353322) that solves the issue

Comment: @caramba, OK, maybe so. I wouldn't know. What I know is that the question here is about **keypress** and the link refers to **clicking**, which is **irrelevant**. The main point and issue here is why the `removeEventListener()` as it is set above does not work, which indeed doesn't.  So the question is **unanswered** and yet closed! So, whoever closed it, should at least refer to **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript**, which **does contain** a solution, and a great one (by member **user8967105**.)