# How should I wait for user input?

Tags: javascript

I'm making something like a text adventure game in Javascript, in a browser.

I've made almost all of it except the bit of logic that actually handles user input and the programme's response to said input. Currently, I'm a bit stumped on the best way to go about this.

My current idea is a recursive `switch` function:

```
mainLoop("Introduction");

function mainLoop(section) {
    switch(section) {
        case "Introduction":
            // Do stuff with the introductory scene
            // Await input
            mainLoop("Gather supplies");
            break;

        case "Gather Supplies":
            // Do stuff
            mainLoop("Make a decision");
            break;

        case "Make a decision":
            // Do stuff
            // Await decision (userDecision)
            if(userDecision == "Left") {
                mainLoop("Ending 1");
            } else {
                mainLoop("Ending 2");
            }
            break;

        case "Ending 1":
            // Do stuff
            break;

        case "Ending 2":
            // Do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

My issue is that I have no idea how to await user input.

I've considered having a `while` loop run forever and only progress when it receives a signal from some `handleUserInput()`, but as I understand it, that would take up the whole thread - I couldn't run another `secondaryLoop()` with its own `while`s alongside the `mainLoop()`.

What's the best way to go about this?

EDIT: I should specify that detecting the input itself is already set up. The user types their sentence/command, it's passed to `handleUserInput()` which (in this example) would then generate a string corresponding to the relevant `case` in the mainloop. If I were to not use this technique, then `handleUserInput()` would do whatever the mainloop requires it to do.

Comment: Is the app running in node or web browser?

Comment: @phuzi It's in a web browser.

Comment: what about eventlisteners for key events? instead of infinite loops, just wait for the next mouse or key click?

Comment: in that case you'll need to register event handlers on whatever input controls you have

Comment: event listener on input field, so you would run `mainLoop(section)` on submit

Comment: You could consider using a button, when the user clicks the button it submits the text they've entered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Comment: Say I were to run `mainLoop("Make a decision")` from the submit - would I then need to assign a different `case` to each choice?

Comment: Your thinking about this wrong. You want your code to event-oriented if you want your code to something when an event happens. So instead of having a main loop, JavaScript is already set up to be event driven with the DOM through event listeners. It already has an event loop.

Comment: its not as simple as event listener...because you need some type of game loop...and consistent behavior across computers and browsers....id imagine there's a framework out there for games in javascript

Comment: Since your function is recursive already, it is perfectly suited for callback style. `case "Make a decision": onNextInput(userDecision => { … mainLoop(…); … }); break;`

Comment: @Bergi: This seems to be the sort of thing I'm looking for - how would I define `onNextInput()`? It seems the contents of that function would answer my question

Comment: @snazzybouche You said "*detecting the input itself is already set up. The user types their sentence/command, it's passed to …*". This should happen in `onNextInput` and call the callback argument. It probably outputs some text and installs event listeners on buttons or something, I don't know - can you show us what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer.

I eventually worked out how to do this, and it was a lot simpler than I expected.

I began by passing the `case` arguments to a function that provided those options to the user. Where input from the user was not required, I bypassed this step, and called `mainLoop` as above with the next `case`.

```
mainLoop("Introduction");

function mainLoop(section) {
    switch(section) {
        case "Introduction":
            // Do stuff with the introductory scene
            presentOptionsToUser(["Gather supplies"]);
            break;

        case "Gather Supplies":
            // Do stuff
            mainLoop("Make a decision");
            break;

        case "Make a decision":
            // Do stuff
            presentOptionsToUser(["Ending 1","Ending 2"]);
            break;

        case "Ending 1":
            // Do stuff
            break;

        case "Ending 2":
            // Do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

`presentOptionsToUser` takes the array of possible options and creates buttons for the user to press (or some other form of input). These buttons have `mainLoop` functions associated with them - for example, `mainLoop("Ending 1")`.

In this way, the recursive loop is maintained, but is broken up by user input.