# use onkeydown or onkeyup to trigger a function without setting up an input Javascript

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

Right now I have this:

```
<form>
    <input onkeydown='changeColor()'>
</form>
```

But can I use the `onkeydown='changeColor()'` outside of an input? So the user doesn't see anything but when they press a key down the changeColor function is triggered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an element focusable with the `tabindex` attribute.

Then when it is focusable you can set on it the keydown binding.

And when the focus is on it and you press a key it will fire the event handler.

```js
function sayHello(){
 console.log("HELLO!");
}
```

```html
<div id="focusable" tabindex=0 onkeydown='sayHello()'>
A DIV
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'keydown' and 'keyup' events with the document or window object for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are global event handlers. And there is one for key press, which can be attached to window object:

```
window.onkeypress = function(ev) {
    myObject.dataLog += String.fromCharCode(ev.charCode);
}
```

Fur further informations take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress).

Answer (score 0):

You can attach keyboard events, almost(as of `HTML5` any element can get `tabindex` attribute), to any `HTML` element. Using the `tabindex` attribute, you can make an element focusable, thus, it will accept keyboard events.

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.focusable'), l = els.length, c = 0;
for(; c < l; c++) {
  els[c].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = (this.style.backgroundColor == 'green') ? 'white':'green';
    console.log('Keydown event on element with ID = ' + e.target.id);
  });
}
```

```css
/* just for this demo */
.focusable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="focusable" tabindex="0">Press a key</div>
<div id="div2" class="focusable" tabindex="0">Press a key</div>
<div id="div3" class="focusable" tabindex="0">Press a key</div>
<div id="div4" class="focusable" tabindex="0">Press a key</div>
```

**A word about `tabindex` attribute**

`tabindex` attribute allows an element to be accessible through `TAB` key, some elements have this behaviour even without specifying the `tabindex` attribute such as `input` elements...

`tabindex` attribute accept only numeric values. An example to illustrate:

`tabindex="X"`: here "X" means a positive number. As the value of "X" gets bigger the element loses priority in terms of accessibility by the `TAB`, so, `tabindex="1"` is thea first, it  has bigger priority comparing to other elements.

`tabindex="0"`: the recommended value, with that you preserve the order of the elements in the page when pressing `TAB` key.

`tabindex="-1"`: with that, you make the element non-accessible through the `TAB` key, but you make it programmatically focusable(useful when you want to make a modal popup that can be closed with the `ESC` key).