# How can i detect a typed string on page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

I would like to use Barcode authentication for my code. Barcode scanner works like a keyboard (plug&play). How can i detect a string typed via keyboard(eg. 599948375), without using a textbox?

So i would like to run a trigger in the background what detect a typed string. I don't want to use textbox to avoid unnecessary clicking. Any tip?

Comment: You mean like a keylogger?

Comment: Is this a web page we're talking about? [Simplest way to detect keypresses in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, like a keylogger.

Comment: Almost every barcode scanner out there, when programmed correctly, can send a carriage return and/or a line feed at the end of every read, so no more clicking a button, it automatically submits the form whit the input's value.