# Is there a way for a website to detect keypresses?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there was anyway that a webpage could wait for certain keypresses and then display information, such as I type something along the lines of **aboutme** and the webpage redirects to an about me page(however the text they type is not visible). I sort of gained inspiration when I learned that you can advance onto a unsafe website by typing *thisisunsafe* in google chrome and was wondering if that functionality could be implemented into a website.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event ?

Comment: yes, you can do this with the keypress event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.code` where `e`  the event listener defined in the function and `.code` is the `keys code` that is being triggered... See my example below taken from MDN Documentation...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

```js
const log = document.getElementById('log');

document.addEventListener('keypress', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent+= `${e.code}` + ' - ';
}
```

```html
Get the key being pressed in your browser

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use an `EventListener` and you're good to go

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
  *do what you want to do here*
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp