# How do you detect if a key is being pressed?

Tags: html, keyboard, key, detection

I am fairly new to *HTML* and I'm starting a new project to help me learn, but I don't know how to detect if a ***specific*** key is being pressed and I can't think of anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Comment: @RobertHarvey ill try that thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect such kind of events by using only HTML code. You have to write javascript or jquery code along with your HTML code to archive this functionality.

Below is one of the example of jQuery code where we are increasing value by 1 every time when pressing key on input field.

```
$("input").keypress(function(){
$("span").text(i += 1);
});
```

Note: if you want to learn basic, i would like to suggest [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/) for the same.