# Function not returning true

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I've been trying to make a simpler way to check for keypresses for my game.
I really thought this would work. I think it's to do with the event listener.
Just wondering why its not working. And is there a more efficent way to do this?

Code:
`

```
    const Key = {
      isDown: function(name){ 
        document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
          if(name == event.code){
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          };
        });
      }
    };

    function checkKeys(){
      if(Key.isDown('Space')){
        console.log('true')
      };
    };

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      checkKeys();
    };
```

`

For some reason `Key.isDown(KEY)` is not returning true, but it is returning false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect keypresses in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/how-do-i-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, keypress is deprecated, use keydown or keyup as an event type

Comment: It's not that I don't know how to detect key presses. I am just trying to develop a cleaner and simpler way of doing it.