# How to disable only submit form with ENTER

Tags: javascript, html

Following my code:

```
<form action="test.php">
<input type="text" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode==13) console.log('something');"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

How to disable submit of form with ENTER key and run correctly the onkeyup with pure javascript?

Comment: `if(event.keyCode==13) console.log('something'); return false;`

Comment: It's works inline, but not if onkeyup calls a function... jsfiddle.net/wrhSy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`return false`** will prevent from submitting

```
if( event.keyCode== 13 ) {
  console.log('something');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It's works inline, but not if onkeyup calls a function... http://jsfiddle.net/wrhSy/

Comment: @user2992868 check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wrhSy/2/  Also take  a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)