# keypress event not generated in chrome but works in ie and ff

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This question has been asked plenty of times before, but no answers I have found seem to solve my problem.

From a classic asp page I call a Javascript function

on each of my pages.  The point is to fire a search button when a user enters search text and presses enter, rather than clicking on the button, or choosing from the Ajax provided selections.

This works fine in IE and FF, as has been the case for every other question asked along these lines.

Here is the Javascript.  Can anybody tell me please how to have it work for Chrome as well as IE and FF ?

---

Edited following answer form Alexander O'Mara below:

Altered function call in body tag on page to use onkeyup instead of onkeypress -  onkeyup="KeyPress(event)"

Altered JS function (also after heeding comments re duplication from others - thanks) as follows:

```
function KeyPress(e)
{
var ev = e || window.event;
var key = ev.keyCode;

if(window.event) // IE
    {
    key = e.keyCode;     
    if (key == 13)
        {
        window.event.keyCode = 0;
        $('#btnSearch').click();
        }
    }
else if (key == 13)
    {
    btnSearch.click();
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    }
 }
```

It seems to work sometimes and not others, and rarely on chrome currently.  Is there a guaranteed way to have it work all the time ?

The main page of my site if you want to try it yourself is www.dvdorchard.com.au, your cursor will be sitting in the search box on arrival - enter a word > 3 chars and press enter, if you stay on the page it didn't work, if you move to the productfound.asp page it worked.

Thanks again.

Comment: *"The point is to fire a search button when a user enters search text and presses enter"* **A form will submit when the user presses enter in one of its text fields**. No javascript required. Have you bound the event you want to trigger to the click of a button instead of the submission of a form? That's a common mistake.

Comment: After the first two lines of your function, `ev` contains `e` or `window.event`.  So you don't need to check `window.event` later on.  You will notice that `btnSearch` is not the same thing as `$('#btnSearch')` so I would suspect that is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup)).  The `keypress` event is not consistent across browsers. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown) for information on the differences.

**Update:**

Since you are using jQuery, you can also remove the `onkeyup="KeyPress(event)"` attribute for you body, and replace your `KeyPress` function with the following (replacing the contents with your event handling code).

```
$(window).keyup(function(e){
    /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this was the simple solution, use onkeyup instead of onkeypress in my body statement.  Javascript is fine as it is, albeit no dubt longer than it has to be.  All fixed.

Comment: But wait, it doesn't work all the time ?  Can't get it working on my default page on Chrome at all currently.  How is it that it works some times and not others ?    Currently I call from the body statement - <body language="javascript" onkeyup="KeyPress(event)"> - and I have updated the javascript function above.  Very frustrating - can anyone help ?

Comment: @user3594771 Perhaps you have conflicting code on the page? You could post another question with an example.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your persistence.  You can look at my site for an example - dvdorchard.com.au.  However, there is still the inconsistencey of the whole thing, works some times, not others, while the content hasn't changed ?

Comment: @user3594771: Seems to work every time for me. Since you are using jQuery, consider using `$(window).keyup(function(e){/*event handling code here*/});`. Using JavaScript attributes like `onkeyup` in your HTML is considered bad-practice, as it's very easy for a script to conflict with another this way.

Comment: Good to know that it's working for you - which browser were you using ? I test in FF, Chrome and IE8.  Sorry to say I probably follow a lot of bad practices, I just do what is necessary to get it working. Would you mind writing out your JQuery comment in full for me, where I would put it etc ?  I have the function call in the body tag of every single page on my site, and a common js page attached to all of them as well (which is where the js code currently sits).

Comment: @user3594771: Tried Firefox and Chrome, both worked. I've added the jQuery details to my answer.

Comment: OK, this is getting annoying.  I refer back to my comment above where I mention this works some of the time and not others.  I can get it working on the default page (with the JQuery code) and on all the other pages on the site (old JS from body tag).  Generally it works without fail on all pages except for those with the carousel operating on them.  I presume the workings of the carousel interfere with it - but only if the carousel is doing something at the time perhaps.  Is that possible ?

Comment: Hi Alexander.  Thanks for your help with this.  I found a setting in my carousel to disable keyboard events. That has fixed the issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(e.keyCode)
  {
    key= e.keyCode;
  }
  else
  {
    key = e.charCode;
  }
```

Fire your event with `onkeyup`

[read more](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

this should work in chrome. I don't know about other browsers

```
function code(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return(e.keyCode || e.which);
}
window.onload = function(){
    document.onkeypress = function(e){
        var key = code(e);
        // do something with key

        // done doing something with key
    key=0
    };
};
```