# Execute JavaScript function when period key pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fire a javascript function called 'faster' whenever the period key is pressed. I first tried a method which had worked for other keys:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) { 
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt = evt || window.event;
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
     case 190:
         faster();
          break;
   }
};
```

I also tried this with the code 46, but still no luck. One post said that Mac keyboards are less reliable and suggested using onkeypress instead of onkeydown. I couldn't find a directly relevant example, but I tried this:

**JavaScript**

```
periodetect () {
    var c = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (c=46) {
       faster();
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<BODY BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC" onkeypress="periodetect()">
```

Can anyone spot my beginner mistake or suggest alternative?

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but `c = 46` is assignment, you should use `c === 46` for comparison.

Comment: It should also be `function periodetect()` not just `periodetect()`

Comment: and I'd use camelCase: `periodDetect()` so that both d's are there. Function names shouldn't be a siamese twin that shares letters. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `keydown` appears to be the right thing to use after all.  It also turns out that `keyCode` is not capitalized in the OP's code given in the comment to my answer, but *is* correctly capitalized in the question.  The examples below *do* work now that I've changed the first one.

Have a look at this: [onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) { 
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt = evt || window.event;
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
     case 190:
         faster();
          break;
   }
};
```

Edited to add:  Can someone test this code in a Mac, please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stack Overflow Tester</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>    
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.onkeydown = function(evt) { 
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt = evt || window.event;
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
     case 190:
         alert("Faster!");
          break;
   }
};
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Stack Overflow Test; press the period.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I have tried all suggested methods (except for the jquery) and I still can't detect the period key. I suspect it may be something about the Macintosh keyboard. Instead of trying to guess what the keycode for period is on my machine, is there some way I can get a script to tell me what code it is receiving when I hit the key?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, in your own first code example, you changed `onkeydown` to `onkeypress`, like above, and it doesn't work on a Mac?  I couldn't make this work in a fiddle.  I'm going to edit my answer to include complete code; can someone please check it on a Mac?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both onkeydown and onkeypress with both 190 and 46

Comment: ok, your test came up 190, as it should, but I still can't trap it. Here is my routine:document.onkeydown = function(evt) { 
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt = evt || window.event;
     // alert(evt.keyCode);
      switch (evt.keycode) {
      case 190:
         faster();
          break;
       //alert(evt.keyCode);
      }
};           The first alert shows 190, the second fails to fire. Could I have something illegal in some other routine that is messing with the interpreter?

Comment: Check capitalization of keyCode in your switch statement.

Comment: Small k large C.          My next move, when I have time, will be to start stripping code out of the page, piece-by-piece, until the case 190: starts working. If it never does, I will just have to redesign my interface.

Comment: Nope.  In the code you pasted above, you have `switch (evt.keycode)`.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I had tried it both ways. Your routine works, so my question is answered. I will have to explore why this won't work on my page.   Thanks for your help

Comment: In your own code, put an alert before the call to faster().  Perhaps it is faster that's failing, and not the capture of the keystroke.

Answer (score 3):

This might be the solution you are looking for:
*Requires jquery 1.9.x or later*

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 190) {
        alert("you pressed .");
    }
});
```

When you press the "period key" and alert will show, if you want it with a function just replace `alert("you pressed .");` with `faster();`

Test it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/d60jtqdc/