# Ctrl + Enter with JavaScript to prevent the enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to save a message when user press ctrl and enter at the same time, here is my code

```
if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    saveMessage();
}       

<textarea placeholder="Add a note..." id="note-content" ng-model="noteContent" ng-keyup="triggerform($event)"></textarea>
```

It works however, it would keep create a extra enter at the end of line which is trigger by the enter key, is there a way i can prevent the enter?

Comment: try e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey

Comment: @AbdulJabbar thanks mate, it does the same thing on my mac, create extra space then submit the action

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code? Like what triggers `e`

Comment: @rybo111 the ng-keyup by angular so the event should be correct.

Comment: The character is added on key down. Maybe you can check if the submit is done on key up ? If it is the case, that could be easy to differenciate the two events.

Comment: @rybo111 thanks you wake me up to try different key down key press :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ng-keypress` instead of `ng-keyup`.

[keydown vs keyup vs keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

> In order to understand the difference between keydown and keypress, it
>   is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a
>   "key". A "key" is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a
>   "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button.  In theory, the
>   keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released,
>   while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The
>   implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.