# Replace input text value by text in a string in REALTIME

Tags: javascript

What I need :
When I press any key on my keyboard in an input text, I replace it by the content of a string.

This is what I have : https://jsfiddle.net/ypcxu27o/

```
<input id="edValue" type="text" onKeyUp="edValueKey()">


function edValueKey()
{
    //var moninput = document.getElementById("edValue").value;
    var monTexte = 'This is my test';
    var cptTexte = document.getElementById("edValue").value;
    cptTexte = cptTexte.length;
    //alert(cptTexte);
    document.getElementById("edValue").value = monTexte.substr(0, cptTexte);
    //document.getElementById("edValue").innerHTML = 'yuty';
}
```

My problem is that we see the key press before my script replace it.
Is-it possible to hide it ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are using the wrong event. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown).

Comment: I have read this post before but with the others 'onKeyPress' and 'onKeyDown', the last character is not replace by my function.

Comment: No? Then you'd need `keyup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
document.getElementById('edValue').addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
  var monTexte = 'This is my test';
  if(ev.which !== 8) {  //everything except backspace
    this.value= monTexte.substr(0,this.value.length+1);
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="edValue" type="text">
```

Comment: yes ! that's exactly what I need ! Thank you. And thank's to everybody for their answers

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<input id="edValue" type="text" onKeyPress="edValueKey(event)">

function edValueKey(e) {
    var monTexte = 'This is my test';
    var cptTexte = document.getElementById("edValue").value;
    cptTexte = cptTexte.length + 1;
    document.getElementById("edValue").value = monTexte.substr(0, cptTexte);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

see also the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ypcxu27o/23/

changes:

- use onKeyPress instead of onKeyUp event
- use e.preventDefault() to prevent showing the original input
- use cptTexte.length + 1 to account for the newly entered character

Answer (score 0):

you can try some kind of css trick here , like at initial stage keep font transparent.

```
 $('#edValue').css('color','transparent');
```

and after at the end performing your operation set color black again `$('#edValue').css('color','black');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="edValue" type="text" onKeyUp="edValueKey()">

function edValueKey()
{
    var monInput = document.getElementById("edValue");
    var monTexte = 'This is my test';
    var cptTexte = monInput.value;
    monInput.value = monTexte.substr(0, cptTexte.length);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ypcxu27o/25/