# Javascript CTRL-C is triggered in <textarea>

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, hidden

Sorry, I am not a very best Javascript-programmer, but I am making a  homepage for my website ( http://coins.kalf999.com/menu.php) and I was producing some code, but I was suprised it did not work untill....now!

But I still not understand why....
Who can help me..?

I made some small code to show the difference.

In the 1st textarea I can copy some text, press CTRL-C, which hides the textarea and you can test the contents of the clipboard in the 2nd textarea. I use a 1 millescond setTimeout-function, which works !

My old code was the second example:
In the 3rd textarea I can copy some text again, press CTRL-C, which hides the textarea and test the contents of the clipboard in the 4rd textarea. 
I not use setTimeout-function, which , obviously, not works !

I can not imagine that a "hidden" object is creating a malfunction for a Copy-command.....

What happens over here...? ;(

I made test-program called tst.html and tst.js

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tst.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "box1"></div>
<div id = "testarea1"></div>
<div id = "box2"></div>
<div id = "testarea2"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML= '<textarea rows="4" onkeypress="CTRLC1(event)">Select some text and copy with CTRL-C.The <textarea> becomes hidden.</textarea>';
document.getElementById("testarea1").innerHTML= '<textarea rows="4" ">Paste text with CTRL-V</textarea>';
document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML= '<textarea rows="4" onkeypress="CTRLC2(event)">Select some text and copy with CTRL-C.The <textarea> becomes hidden.</textarea>';
document.getElementById("testarea2").innerHTML= '<textarea rows="4" ">Paste text with CTRL-V</textarea>';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS-file test.js

```
function CTRLC1(event) {    
    if (event.ctrlKey == true){
        var x = event.which || event.keyCode;    
        if (x==99 || x==67){
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("box1").style.visibility ="hidden";}, 1);
        }
    }
}
function CTRLC2(event) {    
    if (event.ctrlKey == true){
        var x = event.which || event.keyCode;    
        if (x==99 || x==67){
        document.getElementById("box2").style.visibility ="hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both are not working with the code you provided http://jsfiddle.net/g5c0pgwj/1/

Comment: On my computer the first one works, the 2nd one does not work. I work with  FireFox Developer....

Comment: ah, both don't work on chrome, but firefox you're right, the first one paste like expected

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `onkeydown` instead of `onkeypress`.

> In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers. More info: [onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucianmoldovan/g5c0pgwj/3/

Notice that on the second box, though the box gets hidden the text doesn't get copied. I imagine that the element is being hidden before the text gets copied to clipboard. Adding that `setTimeout` fixes this, even if you set it at `0` milliseconds.