# jquery-textfield not clearing properly if i give val function after alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i am working on jquery validation. here I have two text field where the user can enter only number if user trying to enter by mistaken alphabets it should say digit only.

With my current code this is working perfectly fine but the text is not clearing properly.

here is the jquery code

```
 $('.txt_CC').on('change',function(e){

        var len = $('#txt_CC').val().length;
        if(len == 1){
            $('.cc_field').val( '00' + $('.cc_field').val());
        }else if(len == 2){
        $('.cc_field').val('0'+ $('.cc_field').val() );
        }else if(len == 3){
        }
    }); 

  $('.txt_CC').keypress(function(e){
         if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                //display error message
                $('.txt_CC').val('');
                    alert("Digit only");
                }
        });
```

Please suggest me whether my code is correct

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/m2vxLb4g/) for the html

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `return false;` after the `alert` so the event of key pressing an alphabet character does not pass through?

Comment: Use `keyup` instead of `keypress` - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/m2vxLb4g/3/

Comment: Whether can we write two function like this or is that poosible can we make two function in a single one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m2vxLb4g/4/)**

You can do `e.preventDefault()` if it was a character by preventing text to be entered in it instead of clearing. For ex:

```
$('.txt_CC').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("Digit only");
    }
});
```

---

**Update**

Just add `phone number` elements class too into `keypress` event as below:

```
$('.txt_CC,.pn_field').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
               e.preventDefault();
               alert("Digit only");
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m2vxLb4g/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

You are using keypress change for keyup.
[onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)