# Which browsers use which key event system?

Tags: javascript, compatibility, keystroke

I notice that Javascript code seems to be written to read keystrokes in completely different ways, which I guess is to support different browsers. For example, here is one code block from a web page:

```
if (document.addEventListener)
{
   document.addEventListener("keydown",keydown,false);
   document.addEventListener("keypress",keypress,false);
   document.addEventListener("keyup",keyup,false);
   document.addEventListener("textInput",textinput,false);
}
else if (document.attachEvent)
{
   document.attachEvent("onkeydown", keydown);
   document.attachEvent("onkeypress", keypress);
   document.attachEvent("onkeyup", keyup);
   document.attachEvent("ontextInput", textinput);
}
else
{
   document.onkeydown= keydown;
   document.onkeypress= keypress;
   document.onkeyup= keyup;
   document.ontextinput= textinput;   // probably doesn't work
}
```

Judging from this code it would appear different browsers have completely different keystroke handling mechanisms. Which of the above mechanisms corresponds to which browser(s)?

Comment: Read MDN: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: The events you list there in the code are not identical at all, they got different purposes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown

Comment: http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. Basically, all non-archaic browsers do support the standard `addEventListener` these days.

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` is supported by:

- All modern browsers (including Microsoft Edge, and IE9-IE11 when *not* in their broken "compatibility" mode)
- Nearly all old browsers that aren't from Microsoft

`attachEvent` is supported only by older browsers from Microsoft (or IE9-IE11 when in the broken "compatibility" mode).

The `document.onkeydown =` style hasn't been needed anytime this century, that was a *seriously* old mechanism (which still works) from before IE5.5.