# How can I call a function that fires after an integer value is entered into the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call a function that fires only after an interger value is typed into an input field? (So any number 0-9)

```
Col <input type="text" value='tiledata.col' ng-model="tiledata.col" class="input-col" id="aeS-Col" ng-click="vm.setInputCol()">
```

Comment: Please correctly tag your question. If you are going to use jQuery, you can _filter_ events.

Answer (score 0):

yes ..we can do by

```
       document.getElementById('aeS-Col').onkeydown = function(e){};
```

codepen url for reference http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zBrLEj

Answer (score 0):

Well event can be fired on change, but does not depend on the value, but you can check within the onchange event handler function to check for the entered character :

```
element.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var character = keysight(event).char
    //Check if this is a number (eg: using regex)
    //Call function required.
}
```

In your code change the ng-click to `ng-click=vm.setInputCol(event)` and then in the function do the above check and return if not true is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are using angular, you can check like this as well.

```
$scope.vm.setInputCol = function(){

      if(typeof $scope.tiledata.col === typeof 1)
      {
        alert("Do your stuff");
      }
      else
      {
        return;
      };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The .onkeypress() would be the preferred method for doing this. 
[onkeypress vs onkeydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

> In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

So example (in jQuery):

```
$( "#aeS-Col" ).onkeypress( function( key )
{
    if( key.test( /[0-9]/ ) )
        callSuperFunction();
}
```