# Custom placeholder in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a custom `placeholder` in `jquery` since I'm using a `contenteditable` attribute.But for some reasons I can remove the `placeholder` when I start typing text but it isn't working when I'm trying to remove the text.

HTML

```
<div class="FormDescriptionContainer">
    <div class="FormDescriptionPlaceholder">Iam a placeholder</div>
    <p class="FormDescription" contenteditable="true" ></p>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".FormDescription").keydown(function(event) {
        $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'none');
        if($(".FormDescription").text().length<=0)
        {
            $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'block');
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `keyup/input` event instead of `keydown`

As in `keydown`, value of `comtenteditable` is not updated when user has entered some content in `input-element`.

Refer [**onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

```js
$(".FormDescription").keyup(function(event) {
  $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'none');
  if ($(".FormDescription").text().length <= 0) {
    $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'block');
  }
})
```

```css
.FormDescription {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FormDescriptionContainer">
  <div class="FormDescriptionPlaceholder">Iam a placeholder</div>
  <p class="FormDescription" contenteditable="true"></p>
</div>
```

Issue with `keydown`, check the current value printed in `console`,

```js
$(".FormDescription").keydown(function(event) {
  console.log($(".FormDescription").text());
  $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'none');
  if ($(".FormDescription").text().length <= 0) {
    $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'block');
  }
})
```

```css
.FormDescription {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FormDescriptionContainer">
  <div class="FormDescriptionPlaceholder">Iam a placeholder</div>
  <p class="FormDescription" contenteditable="true"></p>
</div>
```

IMO, going with `input` event and having `keyup` as fallback is better approach(considering browser support for `input-event`)

```js
$(".FormDescription").on('input keyup', function(event) {
  $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'none');
  if ($(this).text().length === 0) { //length will never be less than 0
    $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'block');
  }
})
```

```css
.FormDescription {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FormDescriptionContainer">
  <div class="FormDescriptionPlaceholder">Iam a placeholder</div>
  <p class="FormDescription" contenteditable="true"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use keydown, nor keyup event. Use input event.**

```js
$(".FormDescription").on('input', function(event) {
        $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'none');
        if($(".FormDescription").text().length<=0)
        {
            $(".FormDescriptionPlaceholder").css('display', 'block');
        }

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FormDescriptionContainer">
    <div class="FormDescriptionPlaceholder">Iam a placeholder</div>
    <p class="FormDescription" contenteditable="true"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without JavaScript. You can use CSS to see if the element is empty and add text from an attribute.

```css
div[contenteditable][placeholder]:empty:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #CCCCCC; 
}
```

```html
<div class="test" placeholder="TEXT HERE" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Didn't know it was possible that way but can you center the cursor that way I mean if you have text-align:center on your div because it seems like the cursor stays at the start of the div.

Comment: Use `div[contenteditable][placeholder]:not(:focus):empty:before` instead?

Comment: It's working but now the placeholder disappear when focus the div. Instead of disappearing when starting typing text.

Comment: One or the other :) or do it with JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah I see thank you anyway it's a cool way to gonna add this to my list of css tricks :)