# How to take the value from textfield and read on key press event

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am trying to read text present in the textfield. I need to read every character enter at the time when it enter, So therefor I am using

```
keypress: function(cmp,e) { 
        cmp.value;
        cmp.getValue();
    }
```

But this event is fireing as soon as I pressed key. So it not taking the value of key which I entered. It taking in second time. How to resolve it.

How to take the value from textfield and read on key press event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keyup` event instead of `keypress` event.

Check below link for more details.

> [onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

Comment: Can you please elaborate me what is the difference.

Comment: @David - Check above link for more details.