# How can I add onKeyPress event to react material-ui textfield?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I used a `TextField` from react material-ui. I want to know whether the user has pressed Ctrl+Enter. I have tried using `onKeyPress` event but got no result. How can I achieve this?

```
<TextField
    value={this.state.message}
    autoFocus={true}
    hintText='Type your message here'
    onChange={this.onChangeMessage}
    onKeyPress={(event) => {
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == '13')
            this.sendMessage();
    }}
    multiLine={true}
/>
```

Comment: You should've used onKeyDown instead of onKeyPress if you want to be able to get keyCode value.

Answer (score 30):

`onKeyPress` is a synthetic Key event that React supports as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events). Try this code:

```
 onKeyPress= {(e) => {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
              console.log('Enter key pressed');
              // write your functionality here
            }
    }}
```

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you should try onKeyUp instead of onKeyPress

```
<TextField
    value={this.state.message}
    autoFocus={true}
    hintText='Type your message here'
    onChange={this.onChangeMessage}
    onKeyUp={(event) => {
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.key== 'Enter')
            this.sendMessage();
    }}
    multiLine={true}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, onKeyPress isn't triggered for navigation keys or esc but onKeyUp is triggered

Comment: thanks, but for me event.ctrlKey condition fas false for 'enter'

Answer (score 11):

You'd better use `onKeyDown` for this purpose. Here's the reason ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)):

- The onKeyDown event is triggered when the user presses a key.
- The onKeyUp event is triggered when the user releases a key.
- The onKeyPress event is actually an onKeyDown followed by an onKeyUp.

So, the code will be:

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
   if (e.key === "Enter") {
      desiredFunction();
   }
}}
```

Comment: onKeyDown makes the event fire twice for me, unlike onKeyPress

Answer (score 1):

With material-ui, and typscript I am using:

```
              <TextInput
                id="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                onKeyPress={(data: any) => {
                  if (data.charCode === 13) {
                    console.log("Key `Enter` pressed");
                  }
                }}
                value={password}
                onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                  this.setState({ password: event.target.value })
                }
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

```
 <TextField
        value={this.state.message}
        autoFocus={true}
        hintText='Type your message here'
        onChange={this.onChangeMessage}
        onKeyDown={(event) => {
            var evtobj = window.event ? event : e
            if (evtobj.ctrlKey && evtobj.key == 'Enter')
              this.sendMessage()
          }}
        multiLine={true}
    />
```

Answer (score -3):

Please update the onKeyPress event with the below code

```
if ((event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) && event.ctrlKey)
```

Please see the link for [Key Code Values](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Comment: `event.keyCode` was deprecated