# How can I add onKeyPress to a custom React Component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props, onkeypress

I have created an `InputField` component built from Material UI. When I am trying to pass `onKeyPress` to it, it does not work. When I change `InputField` to `input`, the code works. `onKeyPress` is not a prop of `InputField`.

**Input Component:**

```
  <InputField
    className={classes.InputContainer}
    value={props.whatInput}
    onChange={(e) => props.updateInputValue(e, "what")}
    placeholder={"Job title, keywords or school"}
    type="text"
    onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
  />
```

**`handleKeyPress` Function:**

```
const handleKeyPress = (ev) => {
  if (ev.key === "Enter") {
    router.push({
      pathname: "/teaching-jobs",
      query: {
        search_keywords: props.whatInput ? props.whatInput : "",
        search_region: props.whereInput ? props.whereInput : "",
      },
    });
    props.searchWhat();
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

**Tech Stack:**

1. "next": "^9.5.1",
2. "react": "^17.0.2",
3. "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
4. "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
5. "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
6. "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
7. "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.1",
8. "@mui/material": "^5.3.1",
9. "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.5.0",

Comment: refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993523/how-can-i-add-onkeypress-event-to-react-material-ui-textfield this might help you out.

Comment: @SakshiMahajan, thank you for taking the time to share this. Unfortunately, `onKeyDown`, `onKeyUp` and `onKeyPress` do not work. I wonder whether Material UI support these.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`TextField`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/) component:

```
<TextField
  onKeyPress={(e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleEnter();
    }
  }}
/>
```

BTW - `type="text"` is the default for `TextField` so it's redundant here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it this way

```
 onKeyPress= {(e) => {
              console.log(' key pressed');
              handleKeyPress(e)    
    }}
```

For more information you can refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. Unfortunately your suggestion did not work.