# what is difference between working of keyup and keydown in javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keydown, keyup, typescript

I have been just learning the keypress events in javascript and wonder why do i get different result in `keyup` and `keydown`.
for eg. if i assign an input with an id and pass through it a addEventListner[reffer code] then if i type "1234" in keydown event i get output as "123" and this issue doesnt happens with `keyup` event.

in short i just wanted to ask that why in case of
`keydown` no of character(typed in input) is not equal to no. of character displayed in output. this doesnt happens with `keyup` and which one should i use?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="in" placeholder="enter a value" style="border: solid; margin: 15px; padding: 5px">
<div style="border: 5px solid black; margin:10px; width:30vw; height: 15vh">
       Keydown result: <div id="keydown"></div>
</div>
<div style="border: 5px solid black; margin:10px; width:30vw; height: 15vh">
        Keyup result:<div id="keyup"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
document.getElementById('in').addEventListener('keydown', runevent);

function runevent(e){
   
    document.getElementById('keydown').innerText = e.target.value;
    
}

document.getElementById('in').addEventListener('keyup', runevent1);

function runevent1(e){
   
    document.getElementById('keyup').innerText = e.target.value;
    
}


</script>
```

Comment: The `keydown` is fired before the input element is updated (and can be cancelled). See [onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3396754/1715579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in short i just wanted to ask that why in case of keydown no of character(typed in input) is not equal to no. of character displayed in output. this doesnt happens with keyup and which one should i use?

If you're interested in *characters*, use `keypress` if you want to handle the character generated by the events, or use `input` if you just want the latest field value.

- [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) is fired before the character is added to the field, which is why you don't see the `4` after typing `1234`. (An if you prevent the default action of `keydown`, the character is never added.)
- [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) is fired before a change occurs to the input (e.g., before a character is dded if the reason for the change is a keypress).
- [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) is also fired before the character is added. 
  **Note:** `keypress` is deprecated, see [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) and [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event).
- [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) is fired after the character is added.
- [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) is fired after the character is added.

This may help you see the sequence:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("field");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

function handleEvent(e) {
    output.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
       "<pre>" + e.type + ": " + input.value + "</pre>"
    );
}

input.addEventListener("keydown", handleEvent);
input.addEventListener("keyup", handleEvent);
input.addEventListener("keypress", handleEvent);
input.addEventListener("input", handleEvent);
```

```css
#output pre {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: @MingweiSamuel - Thanks for flagging that up, I should have mentioned it (now have). Deprecated, but never, ever, going away (regardless of the wording of MDN's standard deprecation notice). 

Answer (score 1):

The **KeyUp** event is triggered when the user **releases** a Key.

The **KeyDown** event is triggered when the user **presses** a Key.

> The **keydown** event occurs when the key is pressed, followed immediately
>   by the **keypress** event. Then the **keyup** event is generated when the key
>   is released.
>
> In order to understand the difference between keydown and keypress, **it
>   is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a
>   "key"**. A "key" is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a
>   "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button.  **In theory, the
>   keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released**,
>   while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The
>   implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers