# how to capture event on select tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used react-select for drop-drown feature in my application. I want to capture whether user has pressed the "Enter" button/key. I have done something like this:

```
render(){
 const props = {
  className: 'search-combobox',
  placeholder: "search something",
  onChange: this._onSelectionChange.bind(this),
  onSelect: this.props.onSelectedItem,
  options: this.state.options(),
  filterOptions: this._filterOptions.bind(this),
  onInputChange: this._onInputChange.bind(this),
  valueKey: 'id',
};

return(
<Select {...props}
  autoFocus={true}
  clearable={true}
  closeOnSelect={true}
  escapeClearsValue={true}
  onBlurResetsInput={false} />);
}
```

So on _onInputChange method, I tried  this._onInputChange.bind(this, event). It didn't work. How to capture event then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onKeyDown` prop on `react-select` to capture a key press event

```js
<Select options={options} onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
```

And check which key is pressed using `event.keyCode` (13 is for ENTER)

```js
const onKeyDown = event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // enter has been pressed
  }
};
```

> Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-stackoverflow-60219803

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated. You should be using `e.key === 'Enter'` (or `e.code === 'Enter'`) instead. You can check out the values for `e.key` and `e.code`, alongside the older and deprecated properties at https://keyjs.dev.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer will work fine. I have attached link for keycodes incase if you want to change key.

https://keycode.info/

For enter it is 13.

Also bind required event according to below post.

[onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated. You should be using `e.key` or `e.code` instead. Also, there's an alternative tool that will give you more detailed information about the different values and properties: https://keyjs.dev 