# Javascript not reading single character from input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I am having a problem in Javascript. In the code below, there are 2 input field with id's "v1" and "v2" respectively. When I try to log the value of input field v1 with only a single character, nothing is shown in the console. After entering the 2nd character, the console shows the first character.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="v1" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="v2" />

    <script>

        document.getElementById("v1").onkeypress = function() {myFunction()};

        function myFunction() {
            console.log(document.getElementById("v1").value);
            document.getElementById("v1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
         }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown

Comment: Keypress captures the text before the key-down, switch to key-up.

Comment: The keypress event fires before the control's value is updated. Try using the `change` event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `onkeypress`, use `onkeyup`. The reason why it is not working with `onkeypress` is because it generates console when the key pressed. Till then, the value has not entered the input field, meaning that it'll give value which is already there. Using `onkeyup` executes, when the character gets typed in the input field.

```js
document.getElementById("v1").onkeyup = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("v1").value);
  document.getElementById("v1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="v1" /><br>
<input type="text" id="v2" />
```