# How to recognize virtual key codes in KeyPress event?

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl

I am trying to implement something similar to Notepad's insertion of the date and time when users press the F5 key. In the event

```
procedure TFormMain.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
```

the code

```
  if Key=Chr(VK_F5) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('h:nn',now));
  end;
```

has no effect. In the same method,

```
  if Key=Chr(VK_ESCAPE) then
  //do something
```

does something.

What do I need to do for the application to recognize when users press F5?

Comment: Use the KeyDown event instead.

Comment: @Olivier That works! If you'll post a response, maybe with brief explanation about why one uses the KeyDown vs KeyPress event, I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Although this may be helpful to me and those coming to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown

Comment: Yep your question can be considered a duplicate of that one (although it's about JS, but the concept is the same). F5 is not a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Help Form TMemo KeyPress Event:

> Keys that do not correspond to an ASCII Char value (SHIFT or F1, for
> example) do not generate an OnKeyPress event.

F5 is one of those Keys. Try the OnKeyDown Event instead.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_ESCAPE then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Escape')
  else if Key = VK_F5 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('F5');
end;
```

Comment: It's weird that the KeyPress event still recognizes VK_ESCAPE.

Comment: @AlC Escape is not a regular character but it's a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) (with ASCII code 27).