# clearTimeout doesn't clear timer, it seems too late to clear it

Tags: javascript, timer, event-loop, task-queue, debouncing

I'm trying to console.log the input value when the *keyup* event get fired, but similar to *debounce* implementation, from all posible events happened within a range of 1000 miliseconds I want the last one to be fired.

With `clearTimeout(timer)` any previous timer get cleared then a fresh timer is set. So from my view, on entering a string the logs would be like:

```
g
ggg
gggggg
ggggggg
```

Never be repeted.

```js
      let timer = null;
      
      function withdelay() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
          handleChange();
        }, 1000);
      }

      function handleChange() {
        console.log(document.getElementById("texto").value);
      }
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="texto" onkeyup="withdelay()" />
```

**The problem** comes when the time between *keyup* events is close to the delay (1000 miliseconds), the logs are the same.
[image]

Why does that happen?, is there any solution based on this lines?
Here is what I think; once the callback of the timer is load from the *task queue* to the *call stack* to be executed the `clearTimeout(timer)` cannot take effect so the callback continue its execution.

Comment: Solution is to use keypress

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you have to time it right.

Comment: @epascarello I managed :)

Comment: @epascarello Can you explain the problem? I don't understand how this could happen.

Comment: @jabaa just count seconds in your head and hit a character. Try to be as close to intervals of 1s.

Comment: Why don't you use `"keydown"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown

Comment: Now, I got it. `onkeyup` means, if I press a key before the timer runs out, but I release the key after the timer runs out, I'm able to modify the "current" input value and start a new timer for the same input. An answer with a diagram for the timings would be great.

Comment: Also, avoid the use of inline `on*` handlers. Use Element.addEventListener() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is how keypress vs keyup fires.

- keypress fires when the character is added.
- keyup is fired when the key is done being pressed.

So when you release the key the value has already been written. It is not written when you release the key. So the timer picks up the change slightly before you release.

Depending on what you are actually trying to do you may want to use `oninput` or `onkeydown`

Comment: [`Keypress` deprecation notice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) I would highly suggest `"keydown"`

Comment: There is always a `keydown` (an added written character) in between `keyup` events, so by the time `keyup` fires the input value of `document.getElementById("texto").value` should be different from the previous one, but here the value can be repeated, why?

Comment: It is not different because the value was already changed. Key up just means you released the key, it has nothing to do with the value being updated. With the pattern you are doing you are probably better to remove the timer on keydown.

Comment: @epascarello So the value about to be showed when timer runs out can be changed by a `keydown`